# Delta function expressed as integral of exponential problem

Tags: dirac-delta

I've read that the delta function can be expressed as:

δ(t) = $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{j2\pi ft} df$.

The exponential inside the integral can be written as:

$(e^{j2\pi})^{ft} = (cos(2\pi) + jsin(2\pi))^{ft} = 1^{ft} = 1$

So how can we derive from $\int_{-\infty}^\infty df$ to the delta function?

Comment: You can't manipulate complex exponentials like that.

Comment: what is the $\delta $ function ?

Comment: @J.G. Why this is wrong ?

Comment: @ToniIvanov Complex numbers don't in general satisfy $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$. If they did, your argument would show all complex exponentials were $1$.

Comment: @J.G. Oh wow indeed.. subtle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of the [sinc function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function), for small $\epsilon>0$ we get$$\int_{-1/\epsilon}^{1/\epsilon}e^{j2\pi ft}df=\left[\frac{1}{j2\pi t}e^{j2\pi ft}\right]_{-1/\epsilon}^{1/\epsilon}=\frac{e^{j2\pi t/\epsilon}-e^{-j2\pi t/\epsilon}}{j2\pi t}=\frac{1}{\pi t}\sin\frac{2\pi t}{\epsilon}=\frac{2}{\epsilon}\operatorname{sinc}\frac{2\pi t}{\epsilon}.$$This function of $\epsilon$:

- Has $\epsilon\to0^+$ pointwise limit equal to $0$ for $t\ne0$ and $\infty$ for $t=0$;
- Integrates via $\int_{-\infty}^\infty dt$ to $1$, as a consequence of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\operatorname{sinc}xdx=\pi$.

Thus its distributional $\epsilon\to0^+$ limit is $\delta(t)$. In particular, this is a treatment in terms of [nascent deltas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Representations_of_the_delta_function).

Answer (score 1):

One way to define the [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) of a function $\varphi$ is
$$\hat\varphi(f) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \varphi(t) e^{-i2\pi ft} dt.$$

The inverse transform is then given by
$$\varphi(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat\varphi(f) e^{i2\pi ft} dt.$$

Now, strictly speaking, $\delta$ is not a function but a [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)). Still, the above expressions are valid with $\varphi=\delta.$ This gives
$$\hat\delta(f) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(t) e^{-i2\pi ft} dt = e^{-i2\pi f\cdot 0} = 1$$
and
$$\delta(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat\delta(f) e^{i2\pi ft} dt
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 1 e^{i2\pi ft} dt
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i2\pi ft} dt.$$